# Why won't Joomla render my jdoc tags on the frontpage?

Tags: joomla

We just migrated a client from their server to a cloud solution. We moved their Joomla 1.5 site with little issue. The databases were migrated with ease. We had to clean up a few stray 'localhost' database connections. All seemed well and good.

Except the front page. Which for some odd reason refuses to render jdoc tags. At all.

The following HTML is currently found when viewing the front page of their Joomla install:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<jdoc:include type="head" />

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="header-scripts" />
```

This is the only page that has this issue. All other pages on the site render jdoc tags correctly. My google search of this problem seems to end up with most people having the opposite issue: the front page renders fine and the other pages do not. There seem to be other related issues when dealing with newer versions of Joomla, but I cannot connect the difference in code between them, especially as Joomla 2.5.x uses a completely different approach to building the pages.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Notes:

- Joomla 1.5
- MySQL 5.1
- PHP 5.3
- Was running on a dedicated server, now running on a cloud server
- This is my first foray into Joomla, and I am not impressed.
- using YOOThemes as the templating engine (I have read something that this may be the issue, but I have no clue how to fix it.)

Comment: did you left out the closing *</head>* by intention?

Comment: I just copied the code prior to style/link tags. There is other stuff on the page, just not the jdoc tags.

Comment: did you try setting an alternate theme in admin to try to isolate the issue? anything in the logs?

Comment: It happens exactly the same with every alternate theme I try. The logs have a couple of mysql issues related to ZOO for YOOThemes, could this be causing the rendering to fail?

Comment: Fixing ZOO database calls seems to have fixed the front page, while simultaneously breaking the rest of the site. But at least it's a step in the right direction. Thanks @guido.